# grep for the character string "--->"

Tags: bash, shell, unix, grep

How can I search for file containinng the character string `--->`?

```
$ cat arrow
--->
$ grep ---> *
-bash: *: ambiguous redirect
$ grep "--->" *
grep: unrecognized option '--->'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try `grep --help` for more information.
$ grep "\-\-\-\>" *
$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use grep -- to signal end of options

```
grep -- '--->' *
```